# Manipulate DOM after clicking a submit where the request takes a while

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

this might be a very simple question, but cannot really figure it out. If I have a simple form

```
 <form action="demo_form.asp">
   <input type="text" name="user">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

with a quite long request, because it triggers an external API, how would it be possible to trigger JS and show a loading icon in the meanwhile.

```
$('input[type=submit]').on('click', this, FnToShowEl)
```

does not work.
Any idea?

Comment: can't you use an ajax call?

Comment: and how do you want to figure out, when the external api call is completley executed?

Comment: @messerbill well it will when I'm landing on the success page. So basically I wanna show the element as long as the request keeps me on the current page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to submit your form like:

```
$('form').on('submit', function() {
    showLoader();
});
```

Comment: he may not use any ajax

Comment: Ok - i just removed the ajax-part and the return false... So the form will be submitted like normal and show the loader.

Comment: @misantronic doesn't work for some reason. Also should my click attempt then not working too?

Comment: Its worth poiting out that using the submit event is always better than click. You must consider users using keys to submit a form. Did you also try adding a method to your form-tag?